# Make Guzzle POST Request in Laravel using 2 types of authorization

Tags: laravel, post, guzzle

I am trying to make a post request to a url that first requests for a username and password and then I provide the api_key to authorize myself in Laravel but without success. Can you please help?

```
$credentials = base64_encode('username1' .':' . 'password1');
    try {
         $defaultValues = [
             'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Basic '. $credentials,
              ],
              'auth' => 'Bearer ' . $api_key,
              'verify' => false
        ];
        $client = new Client($defaultValues);
$response = $client->post(config('myurl') . '/payments' . '/createPayment',  ['json' => $data]);
```

Thanks

Comment: is the api authentification (the second one) custom made ? share more code or details

Comment: No it is not custom made. $api_key is for the user in laravel to authenticate.
$credentials is for the username and password for the URL

Comment: The token is either passed in the header with "Bearer" or in the request as `'api_token' => $api_key,` withtout the "Bearer" https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#passing-tokens-in-requests

Comment: if you use jwt-auth from tymon the paramter is `'token' => $api_key,` https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/#authenticated-requests

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you said. But still I have another authorization layer. I need to include that in the POST request. The $credentials are not related with Laravel but with the website endpoint that will accept the POST request. To visit that website endpoint it requests username and password. This is the credentials. The token is to authorize user in Laravel.

Comment: read the whole comment. keep the header auth basic and change the input name from `auth`  to `api_token` and remove the `'Bearer'` from the string.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
$credentials = base64_encode('username1' .':' . 'password1');
    try {
         $defaultValues = [
             'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Basic '. $credentials,
              ],
              'api_token' => $api_key,
              'verify' => false
        ];
        $client = new Client($defaultValues);
$response = $client->post(config('myurl') . '/payments' . '/createPayment',  ['json' => $data]);
```